# Struggling with Global Definition of Functions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I haven't used python in ages and I'm struggling with declaring and using a function. I am faced with a global name error when trying to call a function that I have defined.

I have tried using `self` but I am a little lost how this works.

```py
def main(): 
    size = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(size)
    generate = gen(size)
    print(generate)

def gen(self, size):
    #generate...
    return size

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

The error I am faced with is `NameError: global name 'gen' is not defined`.

Comment: *Ooof*... I'm not sure how to go about answering this... suffice to say that the class is not needed and that it should be removed, which 1) improves your code and 2) makes it work?

Comment: This code does not have that error.  The error I get is: `TypeError: gen() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.  Please post the real code you're using.

Comment: `self` is only needed for functions that are members of a class, which `gen()` is not.

Comment: Fix up your indenting. Some people aren't seeing the class declaration. And I don't know whether the last line is in the class definition or not.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks, Just wanted to eliminate the excess stuff, its been updated.

Comment: Why do you even have a class here? It looks like you're trying to write Java in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer the question directly-

```
class paging():
    def main(): 
        generate = gen(size)
    def gen(self, size):
        return size
```

- The only thing in the global namespace here is `paging` which is a class.
- Classes define methods- the global namespace of those methods is `class.method`. Therefore, the name of your function here should be `paging.gen`
- instance methods (the functions you defined there) always take `self` as the first argument, which is a stand in for the instance of the class.
- you can use the self to call other instance methods on the object ...

  def main(self):
      self.gen()

Keep at it, it can be hard to jump in cold

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't need class here, if you want to run your code without the class, you can use

```
import random
import sys


def gen(size):
    # generate...
    return size

def main():
    #Not sure where you are passing pages?
    size = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(size)
    generate = gen(size)
    print(generate)
    print("FIFO", FIFO(size,pages), "page faults.")
    print("LRU", LRU(size,pages), "page faults")
    print ("OPT", OPT(size,pages), "page faults")

def FIFO(self, size, pages):
    return "hello"

def LRU(self, size, pages):
    return "hello"

def OPT(self, size, pages):
    return "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Usage: python paging.py [number of pages]"
    else:
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

- replace this
  `generate = gen(size)`  by `generate = self.gen(size)`
- add `self` as the first argument of `main` method

Comment: How should I go about that? Is it all in the indentation?

Comment: I did not notice you have changed your description, I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that earlier and I ended up with this error: 'NameError: global name 'self' is not defined'.

Comment: self needs to be the first argument of main method, I have updated my answer, I think this should solve your problem

Comment: I also tried that earlier, although was faced with 'TypeError: main() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)' when calling main( ). Is there anything I need to send to the method here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the self. prefix if you're calling a method which is part of the class.
If instead you want to call main() globally, and place it outside the class you should not define the main() and the gen() functions in the class it's self.
so when you call gen() and gen() is not a global function but it's a function which is in the class you should type

```
generate = self.gen(size)
```

Remember that python indentation is the way to have blocks. So if you indent main, main will be in the class block, and it won't be available globally.